# T-SQL Adding each record from a resultset into an existing table without using Cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, loops, cursor

I am pretty new to T-SQL and I am looking for a way to add each record from a distinct select query into an existing table with that records name. I will probably need the use of variables and a loop, just not sure how this is done without cursor because I was told to stay away from having to use cursor.

Here is kind of what I mean (using for each to explain what i need, i know this isnt the format for sql):

```
DECLARE @thename
DECLARE @record

SET @thename = (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tableone) 

FOR EACH @record IN @thename
{
INSERT INTO tabletwo
SET @record = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
}
```

I am using scope_identity because when a record is added to tabletwo it is given an autoincrement id which I will need to reference later on. Any help on how this logic is carried out in T-SQL would be of great help to this novice.

Comment: Can tabletwo have duplicates name? If the answer is no, then name is a candidate key. You don't have to retrieve IDs one by one.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need to do with the identity values later on. If you really need each value, one at a time, to run some procedural code (such as executing a stored procedure), you will need some sort of a WHILE loop (with or without a CURSOR, but likely with).

However, the best performing code will usually use the list of new identity values as a set. Here is how you could capture the newly created identity values using the OUTPUT keyword:

```
-- Set up sample data.

DECLARE @SampleNames TABLE
(
    SampleName varchar(500)
);
INSERT INTO @SampleNames (SampleName) VALUES ('Fred');
INSERT INTO @SampleNames (SampleName) VALUES ('Nancy');
INSERT INTO @SampleNames (SampleName) VALUES ('Jim');
INSERT INTO @SampleNames (SampleName) VALUES ('Nancy');
INSERT INTO @SampleNames (SampleName) VALUES ('Jim');

-- Set up your "tabletwo" destination table

DECLARE @DestinationTable TABLE
(
    DestinationTableID int IDENTITY,
    DestinationTableName varchar(500)
);

-- Set up a holding place for your new IDs

DECLARE @ListOfIDs TABLE
(
    DestinationTableID int,
    UniqueName varchar(500)
);

-- Insert the distinct list of names into the destination table, capturing the generated identity values

INSERT INTO @DestinationTable
(
    DestinationTableName
)
OUTPUT
    INSERTED.DestinationTableID,
    INSERTED.DestinationTableName
INTO @ListOfIDs
    (
        DestinationTableID,
        UniqueName
    )
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    SampleName
FROM    @SampleNames;

-- @ListOfIDs will now contain all of your new IDs.

SELECT
    DestinationTableID,
    UniqueName
FROM    @ListOfIDs;
```

If you really need to execute procedural code for each unique name, you will be hard-pressed to avoid a CURSOR, and you will not be able to avoid a WHILE loop. You could avoid a CURSOR by using SQL Server's XML capabilities to concatenate the unique values into a string, and then use some string manipulation in a loop to extract individual values. This would technically avoid using a CURSOR, but it would not likely have superior performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you want to build your query

```
insert into table2
(field1, field2, etc)
select field3, field4, etc
from table1
where whatever
```

Also the set keyword goes with update queries.  Your question has it in an insert query which will throw an error.

Comment: so i dont have to do any iteration through each record from my distinct query? itll just add each one automatically? If i need to set each record to its own scope identity so i can later reference it how would that effect the insert into?

Comment: then you use the OUTPUt clause to get the whole set of ids